# Force gnuplot to show zeroaxis while letting it autoscale

Tags: gnuplot

I am looking for a way to allow gnuplot to autoscale, but still force the graph to include the say [-1:1] range on the y axis.

instead of an image like this
[image]
 I would want it to look like this

[image]

Less important: if I can get rid of the white space from top and bottom of canvas it would also be good.

My code:

```
set encoding utf8
set yzeroaxis lt 1 lc 8 lw 2
set xzeroaxis lt 1 lc 8 lw 2
set xtics pi
set mxtics 6
set ytics 0.5
set grid mxtics ytics lt 1 lc 3 lw 0.5
unset key
set format x '%.0P'
set samples 5000
set offset graph 0.0, graph 0.0, graph 0.1, graph 0.1
set xrange [-4*pi:4*pi]
set size ratio -1

set terminal pngcairo enhanced font 'Cambria' size 1600,900

do for [t=1:8]{
    A = 0.5*t

    do for [b=2:4]{

    do for [i=-4:4]{
        if(i!=0){
        c = 0.5*i
        outfile = sprintf('Asin(bx)+c/%.2gsin(%ux)%+.2g.png',A,b,c)
        set output outfile
        plot A*sin(b*x)+c lc 7 lw 2 }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: about the white space... Do you want the squares defined by the grid keeping the same size in pixels? So, are you asking for a "dynamic" image size? For example, image width in pixel would stay constant but the image height in pixels would depend on the data?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like. However I do not know how to set terminal size before I know what size my plot is going to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `help xrange` and scroll down...
I guess you are looking for this:

```
set yrange [*<-1:1<*]
```

The y-range will be autoscale but always includes [-1:1].

**Addition:**

About your second question concerning the white margin.
After plotting, the variables `GPVAL_TERM_YMAX` and `GPVAL_TERM_YMIN` hold the values for the bottom and top y-coordinates of the graph on the canvas (or screen or terminal) in "terminal coordinates". In pngcairo, 20 terminal units are 1 pixel. To see more variables type `show var GPVAL`. Since you get these values only *after* plotting you have to replot and adjust the terminal size accordingly. For the x-label you add a little more space, here e.g. `d=80`. I added a light-grey background just for illustration. And I had to adapt your filenames a little.

In case you want to the x-axis at a constant pixel position of the image, you might want to check this: [GNUplot - draw line using window coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58270397/7295599)

**Code:**

```
### adjust canvas to size of plot
reset session

set encoding utf8
set yzeroaxis lt 1 lc 8 lw 2
set xzeroaxis lt 1 lc 8 lw 2
set xtics pi
set mxtics 6
set ytics 0.5
set grid mxtics ytics lt 1 lc 3 lw 0.5
unset key
set format x '%.0Pπ'
set samples 1600
set offset graph 0.0, graph 0.0, graph 0.1, graph 0.1
set xrange [-4*pi:4*pi]
set size ratio -1

set yrange[*<-1:1<*]
set terminal pngcairo background rgb 0xfcfcfc  # background just added for illustration

set lmargin screen 0.03
set rmargin screen 0.97

d = 80
do for [t=1:8]{
    A = 0.5*t
    do for [b=2:4]{
        do for [i=-4:4]{
            if(i!=0){
                c = 0.5*i
                set terminal pngcairo enhanced font 'Cambria' size 1600,900 
                outfile = sprintf('A=%.1g,b=%.1g,c=%.1g.png',A,b,c)
                set output outfile
                plot A*sin(b*x)+c lc 7 lw 2
                set output
                NewHeight = GPVAL_TERM_YMAX - GPVAL_TERM_YMIN + d
                set terminal pngcairo enhanced font 'Cambria' size 1600,NewHeight
                set output outfile
                replot
                set output
            }
        }
    }
}
### end of code
```

**Result:** (just 2 examples out of 90 generated graphs)

[image]

[image]

Comment: @László Ruff, yes the first `set term` is better in the loop. Thanks for the edit.